# wcf wp7 service reference - session/coockie

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cookies

i have and app that use a wcf service reference with the enableHttpCookieContainer="true" in the binding.

enableHttpCookieContainer is not really compatible in visual studio, i need every time that i need to update to delete it.

after few searchs i founded other methods to pass cookies in the wcf requests like this:

```
using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(Channel))
{
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    request.Headers["Cookie"] = CoockieContainer;
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;
}
```

but this don't work for me in wp7.

my question is, what is the officially, clean, compatbile way, to have a session in wcf when use from wp7 service reference? if wcf is hosted in a windows service instead a web site, there is not session, so i really think that the enableHttpCookieContainer is a fail and not clean way...